# How to include CorrelationId in microservice architecture?

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a microservices architecture using ASP.NET Core web api. All the services are decoupled from each other, and may be deployed in different environments. Every service has its own logging. When requests flows through these services it could fail in any of the service, We need a way of tracing a series of events back to the source, even if it means traversing multiple services.
So to handle this issue, the service that originates the request creates a CorrelationId and pass it to the next service. The 2nd service pass it to 3rd service and so on. If exception occurs the corresponding service will log the exception message along with CorrelationId.

I wanted to know what would be a best place for the caller of the service to pass the correlationid?

Should the caller pass correlationid in HttpHeader or should it pass it as a part method parameter something like below

*This is the service that is getting called*

```
 public class RequestDTO
 {
    public string CorrelationId {get;set;}
    public string SomeOtherData {get;set;}
 }

 public Service2Controller:Controller
 {
    public Task<in> DoSomething(RequestDTO request)
    {
         // add the correlationid in current request Items collection
         // So global exception handling can access it and log it 
         // along with the exception

         HttpContext.Items.Add("CorrelationId", request.CorrelationId);
    }
 }
```

in the approach above if there is an exception before this method is invoked, the CorrelationId will not be available for global exception handler for logging.

Any suggestions? or alternate approach

Comment: A custom header is usual as it bypasses issues during deserialization etc. However, why not also pass it in the payload too. No reason you can't have both.

Comment: @TomRedfern is it `typical` to add custom data into http headers?

Comment: @TomRedfern each service can be deployed to different types of environment. My concern was adding custom data into http headers may get denied by the host server. Does hosting server typically checks for unknown headers?

Comment: I've yet to come across a http server which cannot process custom headers. We're using custom headers in our solution with services written in java and .net, with jboss fuse in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation identifier should not be something that you add yourself, some framework that sends the messages should do this. This way a developer can't forget it and it has a consistent behaviour all over the place.

Put a `MessageId` and `CorrelationId` in the headers of the message. On first message, both will be the same. On second message, `CorrelationId` is set to the `MessageId` of the previous one.

You could also set a unique `ConversationId` which never changes, to track all messages spawning from one originator. Useful when using pub/sub and/or calling back to the originator of a message.

Comment: Hi @dennis, won't the strategy above mean that you'd have to write a graph query to view the full log trace for a single transaction? i.e. pretend correlationID starts as 1, and message ID = 1, for next message your strategy suggest the message id of the new message = 2, and correlationID = 1, next message it's now 3 and 2. Now there's no way to see all the log messages for transaction with correlationID 1.

Won't a better strategy be correlationID is *always* the same as the incoming correlationID?

Comment: That's what the ConversationId is for. That stays the same all the time. The CorrelationId are to trace back which previous message (and handler) caused this message to be sent. This is exactly what is done with NServiceBus and how ServiceInsight is able to create flow diagrams of the entire message flow: https://docs.particular.net/serviceinsight/#flow-diagram

Comment: In other words, if you have 1 ConversationId from a logfile or a message-header, you can query using that ConversationId and find all messages that are part of the conversation. Then trace back in which order they were sent by using CorrelationId.

Comment: Ok, that sounds sensible, but that seems to be different to advice given elsewhere relating to x-request-id, x-correlation-id, and request-id. Maybe the names are co-incidentally similar and therefore confusing? (I could easily simply have misunderstood.) The http headers are discussed here : I want 2 track sagas from http client across all services & queues. Any suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068619/should-i-use-request-id-x-request-id-or-x-correlation-id-in-the-request-header#:~:text=For%20X%2DCorrelation%2DID%20%2C,use%20X%2DCorrelation%2DID%20.

Comment: ...what I mean is; for http there appears to be no recommended saga Identifier header, like the `ConversationId` you recommend above, or is there? I guess what I'm getting at, is a conversation about micro services and tracking sagas needs to include tracking that starts with the client, most often a web client and a human user initiating an action. (And we need to make sure that we match up the correct http headers with the correct `service` correlation IDs used by micro services. )

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there are two options. With both of them a user, a WebAPI, a background process, anything can start sending messages.

1. Only a single message is sent. If you use a framework like NServiceBus or MassTransit, the identifiers are added from the start. Otherwise you do it yourself.
2. Multiple messages are sent and they all need the same conversationid/correlationid. That means you have to do it yourself, or use available options. With NServiceBus you can use SendOptions.

If you're sending data over HTTP, I'm not sure anything supports that.

Comment: mmm, ok that makes sense. That fits well with this explanation of what to do specifically for HTTP in this blog post : https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/ See the section where Rico talks about `Scopes,` he says this, `correlation ID (Use the X-Request-ID) Http header, in app Insights the property should be called operationID, also use a Transaction ID. Dont forget to pass the correlation ID when calling other HTTP endpoints.` Thanks for the detailed replies Dennis, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best approach is to

- let a library do it for you and
- to follow standards where available

For example, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-tracing) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation) how Application Insights does dependency & correlation tracking across different levels, using headers. And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044178/8479) for a good description of it too.