# Should I use Request-Id, X-Request-Id or X-Correlation-Id in the request header?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am not clear which id header I should put in the request and response for the correlationship purpose.

"X-Correlation-ID" and the "X-Request-ID" are the known http header.  Does it matter which one I use in the request and response?

ASP.NET Core's System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource looks for the "Request-Id".  Is this for the Activity purpose only?  Why doesn't it use the "X-Request-ID"?

If I don't use the Activity, I don't need to send that header, right?

ASP.NET Core also has the Hierarchical Request-Id (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/HierarchicalRequestId.md
) that I like the idea.   I can do something like this

```
    var newRequestId = $"{context.Request.headers["X-Correlation-ID"]}:{CreateNewGuid()}";
```

OR is it better to use the Activity?  I find the Activity.Current is always null.  Does it need to be enabled and does it affect performance?

Answer (score 34):

For `Request-Id`, it's uniquely identifies every HTTP request involved in operation processing, and is generated on the caller side and passed to callee.

For `X-Correlation-ID`, also known as a Transit ID, is a unique identifier value that is attached to requests and messages that allow reference to a particular transaction or event chain.

For every request, you should use `Request-Id`, for request transaction, you should use `X-Correlation-ID`.

> If I don't use the Activity, I don't need to send that header, right?

For Correlation ID, in general, you don’t have to use one. But if you are designing a distributed system that incorporates message queues and asynchronous processing, you will do well to include a Correlation ID in your messages.

> I find the Activity.Current is always null. Does it need to be enabled and does it affect performance?

For using `Activity.Current`, you need to able `ApplicationInsights`, or implement your own feature to manage activity.

1. Install `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`
2. Configure `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().UseApplicationInsights()`
3. Use like `var activity = Activity.Current;`

Comment: I have App1 -> App2 -> App3,     During App1 -> App2,   Request-Id : App1   
X-Correlation-ID: App1.     During App2 -> App3,   Request-Id : App2   X-Correlation-ID: App1.App2.   And the response will have the X-Correlation-ID back.
Is that what you mean?   If I just want to reference the transaction, I can only send the X-Correlation-ID, right?

Answer (score 1):

The response submited by Edward is correct. However, including a "x-" prefix is deprecated by RFC6648 due some compatibility issues.

[RFC6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6648)

Answer (score 0):

For X-Request-id, I simply used a unique id and boom, my issue was solved.

In Axios.

```
const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl',
        headers: {
            'content-disposition': 'always',
            'X-REQUEST-ID': Math.random(200)
        },
        data: {
            amount: { currency: 'USD', number: 1 },
    };
```